# d3.js adding click action to a force layout circle?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, force-layout

I am working on to create a undirected graph with force layout. In addition, I try to chage each circle's (node's) color with click event. Is there any idea to add such event on the circle elements. I tyry this code however it is not working.

```
vis.selectAll("circle.node").on("click", function(d){
    vis.select(d).attr(r, 25)
    .style("fill","lightcoral")
    .style("stroke","red");
});
```

Comment: Did you mean `attr('r', 25)`?

Comment: I need to do such attr changes however I cannot select the node that is selected. That is I try to use "d" as func. argument to choose circle but it does not work.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`select(d)` references the data, not the element. You need to `select(this)`

```
 vis.selectAll("circle.node").on("click", function(){
            d3.select(this).attr('r', 25)
                .style("fill","lightcoral")
                .style("stroke","red");
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

`vis.select(this)` gives me a DOM exception. `d3.select(this)` works for me. You can also use `d3.event.target` to access the DOM element that is clicked on.